# Intransitivity of a group generated by two 2-cycles (1 2), (3 4)

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, permutation-cycles

I'm recently reading a group theory textbook (Pierre Ramond's book) for physicists and there is a sentence that reads

> The permutation group on four objects, generated by the cycles (1 2), (3 4) is intransitive because it does not contain the permutation that maps [1, 2, 3, 4] to [3, 2, 1, 4].

Here, [1, 2, 3, 4] denotes the order of four objects after a group action.

However, I cannot understand it since there is no element which send those four objects to [3, 2, 1, 4] in the first place.

In other words, an intransitive group can also be defined as a group whose the number of orbits is greater than 1.

In this sence, the group generated by (1 2), (3 4) has only one orbit. I think it is trivial since the explicit elements of the group are given by:
\begin{align}
\{ e, (1 2), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4)\}.
\end{align}

Where did I make a mistake? I look forward to your answer/comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given reason is that the group lacks one specific element of the full permutation group $S_4$.
Howevre, a better (i.e., correct) reason why this group (or rather its canonical action on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$) is not transitive is that we can find elements, e.g., $x=1$ and $y=3$, such that there is no element $g\in G$ such that $g(x)=y$.

The two orbits of  the action of $G$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer!
However, I do not understand what do those two orbits mean.
I think the definition of the orbit of $x \in G$ is: $\{g(x) | g \in G\}$. 
You said that $x = 1 \in G$ (or $y = 3$), but $G$ consists of the permutations $\{e, (1 2), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4)\}$. I want to say that $x = 1 $ is not an element of $G$. 
Hence, I guess the orbit is again given by $\{e, (1 2), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4)\}$ for all element of $G$.
Actually, (1 2) * e = (1 2), (1 2) * (1 2) = e, (1 2)*(3 4) = (1 2)(3 4), (1 2)*(1 2)(3 4) = (3 4) and so on. Is this incorrect?

Comment: OK, may be I managed to understand. I think my definition of the transitivity was incorrect. The correct definition is: The _action_ of $G$ on $X$ is transitive iff the number of orbit of $X$ (**not** $G$), which is a group $G$ acts on, is equal to 1. Is this correct?

Comment: @Keyspire: yes, exactly

Comment: @Jack Schmidt I see! Thank you very much! (and Mr. Hagen von Eitzen, thank you.)